# Symfony2.0 form date with today

Tags: php, forms, datetime, symfony-2.0

I create a form in symfony2.0 and read some articles here. But all doesn't work.

I want to create a form field with the type  `date` and the date should be today. What is wrong?

```
            ->add('date', 'date', array(
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'data'  => new \DateTime() //new \DateTime('today') didn't work
            ))
```

I don't have an entity.

Error message:

Expected argument of type "DateTime", "array" given

How do I pass it right in Symfony2.0?

## Update: Answer

A little bit too much code, but this is the answer.

Before the form builder:

```
$dt = new \DateTime();
```

The form builder:

```
....
'input'  => 'array',
'widget' => 'choice',
'format' => 'dd MM yyyy',
'data'  =>  array('year' => $dt->format('Y'), 'month' => $dt->format('m'), 'day' => $dt->format('d')), 
....
```

Comment: You could also set the date by presetting the field in your entitiy you are using with your form.

Answer (score 1):

In your entity, set the datetime to your field like that :

```
/**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }
```

Comment: In this case I don't have an entity. I did this already and this works.

Comment: Try with just 'data' in your array